# How to hide a custom Button in tree view

Tags: xml, button, odoo, odoo-10

[image: ]([![https://imgur.com/a/CzXG7YL]

I have a custom button "View All" in my List view, i want it to be visible only to a user who have a certain group access how can i achieve it?.

I tried adding groups attribute to the button but it didn't work,

```
<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t  t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="before">
            <button t-if="widget.modelName == 'leave.request.allocation'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_filter_button" accesskey="f" groups="hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_manager">
                View All
            </button> 
        </t>
    </t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ListView their have **render_buttons** function which has on **js** level.
So you can add the condition their to check with the user having your group or not and based on that code to display the button and hide.
Here you go :

```
var ListView = require('web.ListView');
ListView.include({
    render_buttons: function($node) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.session.user_has_group('Your Group').then(function(has_group) {
            if (has_group) {
                // Do Something
            } else {
                // Do Something
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer

`var user_group =  self.getSession().user_has_group('Your Group')` im getting an array here instead of boolean

Comment: `web.assets_backend.js:2474 {state: ƒ, always: ƒ, then: ƒ, promise: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, …}` this is what im getting

Comment: @user9523333 this.session.user_has_group('Your Group').then(function(has_group) {
    if(has_group) {
        // Do Something
    } else {
        // Do Something
    }
});

Comment: Can you please edit the last comment into your answer?